# Oracle - Doing substraction based on different number of rows from different sources

Tags: sql, oracle

I have basically 3 different select statements that retrieves different number of rows based on a key. I would like to do substraction such that no records are dropped off. Even if the 2 select statements returns null, I would still subtract by setting them as 0.

For instance,

```
SELECT COL1, COL2,COL3, (C.EXP_VAL + (A.EXP_VAL-B.EXP_VAL)) AS EXP_VAL FROM 
(SELECT * FROM A WHEN KEY = 1 AND CATE_TYPE=1) A, \\ RETURNS 5 ROWS
(SELECT * FROM B WHERE KEY =1 AND CATE_TYPE=2) B, \\ RETURNS 5 ROWS
(SELECT * FROM C WHERE KEY=1 AND CATE_TYPE=3) C \\RETURNS 10 ROWS
WHERE A.KEY=B.KEY AND A.KEY=C.KEY AND A.COL1=B.COL1 AND A.COL1=C.COL1;
```

In the above example, what I see is that eventually the results only returns the smaller subset of 5 records due to the WHERE clause conditions. How am I able to retrieve all 10 records instead of the smaller subset. Ideally, what I want is 10 records, with those that matches the WHERE CLAUSE being evaluated by the (+,-) AND those not matching also being evaluated by being set to 0. E.g. If C got records and A,B doesnt, it will be c.exp_val + (0-0) with A,B being set to 0.

Comment: probably need to use a left join with NVL function

Comment: Is it possible to find an a or b record for which no c record exists? If so, do you want to see it in your results or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `full outer join`:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, (C.EXP_VAL + (A.EXP_VAL-B.EXP_VAL)) AS EXP_VAL
FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHEN KEY = 1 AND CATE_TYPE=1) A full outer join
     (SELECT * FROM B WHERE KEY =1 AND CATE_TYPE=2) B
     ON A.KEY = B.KEY AND
        A.COL1 = B.COL1 full outer join
     (SELECT * FROM C WHERE KEY=1 AND CATE_TYPE=3) C 
     ON C.KEY = COALESCE(A.KEY, B.KEY) AND
        C.COL1 = COALESCE(A.COL1, B.COL1);
```

If you know that the third subquery always has the most rows, you can rearrange the subqueries and use `LEFT JOIN`.

Also, never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN`s.

Also note that the values from the unmatched tables will be `NULL`, not `0`.  If you want `0`, then use `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

As Gordon already showed, you get all records by using full outer joins. To get it readable use the USING clause, rather than ON:

```
select 
  col1, nvl(c.exp_val,0) + nvl(a.exp_val,0) - nvl(b.exp_val,0) as exp_val
from 
  (select * from a when key = 1 and cate_type = 1) a
full outer join 
  (select * from b when key = 1 and cate_type = 2) b using (col1)
full outer join 
  (select * from c when key = 1 and cate_type = 3) c using (col1);
```

The column that links all records is Col1 explicitly (because it is in the USING clause) plus Key implicitly (because it is set to the same value in all queries). You can add Key to the USING clause `using(key,col1)`, if you want to. It doesn't change anything and is kind of redundant, but you may consider it more readable. Add it or leave it, it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten for your inputs!

Comment: @Thorsten . . . That is a good idea.  I forgot that `using` fixes the `NULL`-value problem with `full outer join`.